# systemd - private temp directories and permissions

Tags: systemd

When setting up private temporary directories, I'm faced with some annoying problems.
Whenever the service (php-fpm in this case) stops, the temporary directory is wiped. Not quite as I want, because PHP expects to find the directories `/tmp/sessions` and `/tmp/uploads` at minimum.

Currently, I have a script that "bootstraps" the creation and permissions of these directories, so that if I restart `php-fpm`, I can re-create them in a jiff.

However, this "directory-creation" script does not solve my problems after all. PHP complains about "Permission Denied" when writing to these folders.
Even if permissions are set to wide open. If I manually create `/tmp/test`, PHP is not able to write to that directory. If I create the directory from within the php-fpm process (e.g. via a HTTP request), then PHP is suddenly able to write there. This makes somewhat sense, that the owner of the private temporary directory (php-fpm), is the one that can do CRUD operations there.

So how can one really "bootstrap" a private temporary directory? It would be nice if the directories got created by systemd itself, or php-fpm when it first starts, but I haven't found a way of doing this.

My last option is to ditch the private temporary directories, but this is really something I don't want to do.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You may need to define `open_basedir` and `upload_tmp_dir` in php.ini, in addition to exporting variables in the apache config for TMP TMPDIR TEMP depending on your OS, so that you are not writing into /tmp which isn't even the proper place for php/perl to write temp files anyway.  If you have SELinux enabled, that dir should have the proper context set to allow read-write by httpd.

Comment: You are missing the point. The PHP process has its own private temporary filespace, managed by `systemd`. The problem I'm having is that PHP is unable to write to directories I create manually in this location (but is able to write if PHP itself creates them). Since ownership and permissions are correct, I suspect that `systemd` knows that the directories where created by me (not the process), and therefore denies PHP access to them..

Comment: I am actually not missing the point at all.  Systemd creates private /tmp space for each user, yes.  I am saying, stop using /tmp.  You can configure a different temp location for PHP to use.

Comment: So do you know why creating the directories manually doesn't work? Something in the manner of: `su - root; mkdir /tmp/systemd-private-XXX-php-fpm.service-YYYY/tmp/test && chown nginx:nginx /tmp/..../test && chmod 0770 /tmp/...../test`. Now PHP should have that directory accessible from `/tmp`, but I constantly get `access denied`.

Comment: Most likely the wrong namespace.  I dont know the version of your OS and systemd.  The behavior in systemd has changed a bit over time.  SELinux can also influence this namespace.  That would be obvious in audit.log however.

Comment: SELinux, of course! A simple `ls -Z` revealed that the directory I had created had security context of `user_tmp_t` whilst the directories created by PHP had `httpd_tmp_t`. Changing security context using `chcon -Rv --type=httpd_tmp_t /tmp/systemd-private-XXX-php-fpm.service-YYYY/tmp/test/` did the trick, for that directory. I'm wondering however if I should change the sec. context to `httpd_tmp_t` for all files under the private `/tmp` or not (some dirs have `var_lib_t`, `httpd_log_t` and so on -- its not always `httpd_tmp_t`).

Comment: Anything relying on finding files in `/tmp` at startup is broken. The contents of `/tmp` cannot be expected to stay around for a long time, and it is generally recommended that `/tmp` is emptied at every boot. If you cannot deal with the files being wiped out, don't put them in `/tmp` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By help from [Aaron](https://serverfault.com/users/261951/aaron) the permission issue was resolved by setting the correct SELinux security context. The "bootstrapping" of private temp space was solved using a custom post-start script in the `systemd` configuration (`/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service`):

```
.include /lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service

[Service]
ExecStartPost=/bin/php -f /opt/www/create_tmp_dirs.php
```

The script itself is responsible for creating directories under `/tmp` (which gets written to the private tmp space), setting correct permissions and ownerships, and of course the correct security context.

When I created the directories manually, the security context was set to `user_tmp_t` whilst the correct context should be `httpd_tmp_t`.